# How to split info in the google sheet if I have comma separator, but at the same time I have comma in the text?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split

I have a lot of rows in google sheet and I need to split them

How can I split them if I have comma in the text?

[image]

I would really appreciate, if you could help me

Comment: `=SPLIT( cell-ref-here, ",")` [Reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

Comment: Thank you! However, in my case it doesn't work as I have comma in the text. Please have a look at the link with an image attached in the description

Comment: Maybe you can put `", "` i.e comma space after each sentence within the cell. And `","` i.e comma without space within the sentence. And match it using regex. Still trying. Let's see what others answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the comma always comes before a number, maybe separated from it by a space, you can try

```
=split(regexreplace(regexreplace(A1,",$",""),", *([0-9])","~$1"),"~")
```

which removes any trailing comma then replaces the commas which come before a number with "~".

[image]